# How to use curl with Post query mutation in php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, query-string, guzzle

I write the code for use api endpoint in my laravel project to get some response.
this endpoint requires me to post with x-www-form-urlencoded containing the query string mutation:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://facemachine.3divi.com/api/v2/' \
--header 'token: 242903fb-7e53-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'query=mutation {
        createProfile(profileData: {personInfo: "{\"name\": \"Name\"}", samplesData: {image: "base64 image"}}) {
          ok, profile {id}}
}'
```

I wrote it this way, but it gave an error

```
$curl = curl_init();
    $name = request()->name;
    $image64 = request()->input('image64');
    $query = 'query=mutation {createProfile(profileData:{personInfo: "{\"name\": \"'.$name.'\"}", samplesData: {image: "'.$image64.'"}}) {ok, profile {id}}}';
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://facemachine.3divi.com/api/v2/',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'charset=utf-8',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $query,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'token:242903fb-7e53-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx',
            'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
    ));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($response);

return $response;
curl_close($curl);
```

errors :

```
"errors": [
        {
            "message": "[{'message': 'cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f8889f46db0>', 'locations': [{'line': 3, 'column': 25}], 'path': ['createProfile']}]"
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "createProfile": null
    }
```

somehow the base64 image won't be read by curl, how i can solve this problem

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you are writing code in curl so why mention guzzle, do you want a guzzle solution as well?